# YAML - Get data on a new yaml attribute

Tags: yaml

I have a YAML file with this data:

```
TEST:
  1: 10
  2: 15
```

and I added new data, and I want to make data of this attribute with the same data of TEST attribute. EX

```
TEST2:
  1: data of the first element of TEST
```

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution (after searches):

```
TEST:
  1: &first_test 10
  2: 15

TEST2:
  1: *first_test
```